# Wiener filtering

Tags: image, image-processing, filter

I want to write a Wiener filter to improve an image. I don't want to use fourier, i know there is a median and variance based alg, but i can't find it. Can you help me guys?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter

Answer (score 5):

[I think this is what you are looking for.](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~rayver/mm/code/cvWiener2/) This code is written by Ray Juang.

example on using above code

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
    if (argc <= 1) {
            printf("Usage: %s <image>\n", argv[0]);
            return;
        }

    IplImage *tmp = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    IplImage *tmp2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(tmp->width, tmp->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    cvCvtColor(tmp, tmp2, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cvNamedWindow("Before");
    cvShowImage("Before", tmp);

    cvWiener2(tmp2, tmp2, 3,3);
    cvNamedWindow("After");

    cvShowImage("After", tmp2);
    //cvSaveImage("C:/temp/result.png", tmp2);
    cvWaitKey(-1);


    cvReleaseImage(&tmp);
    cvReleaseImage(&tmp2);
}
```

Comment: Link to yahoo group message is broken.

Comment: all links are down, I think these are the original sources: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~rayver/mm/code/cvWiener2/